# Eclipse slow after import of yeoman scaffolded angularjs project

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, yeoman

I've created a new Angularjs project using Yeoman.

```
yo angular
```

It create a huge project folder, near 190Mb of node_modules libraries.
Don't know if this is normal, but i've tried to import the created project in eclipse as a new JavaScript project and after that, eclipse become really slow, probably cause isn't able to validate/handle such a big project.

Is it normal that a new AngularJs project scaffolded with Yeoman take so much disk space?

If so, how can I make eclipse handle it?

Thanks for any information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it crashes Eclipse occasionally. My solution is to use Eclipse resource filter to ignore Yeoman related folders.

1. Right click on your project, select Properties.
2. Resource->Resource Filters
3. Click on "Add..."
4. Select "Exclude all" under "Filter type"
5. Select"Folders" under "Applies to"
6. Enter "node modules" in the text box and click on OK
7. Repeat 1-6 for the "bower-components" folder

After these two folders are ignore my Eclipse is running fine. I'm running Luna (4.4.1) btw.